# Converting Collections to Strings, getting invalid method declaration

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment and I feel super close! But I just don't understand the last error message I'm getting and was wondering if you could help me understand it so I avoid it in the future.

The assignment started off with an example code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Proj09{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    new Proj09Runner().getCollection();
    }
}

class Proj09Runner{
    public void getCollection(){
        Collection collection = new TreeSet();
        Populator.fillIt(collection);
        Iterator iter = collection.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(iter.next());
        }
    System.out.println();
    }
}

class Populator{
    public static void fillIt(Collection collection){
        collection.add("Able");
        collection.add("Baker");
        collection.add("aBle");
        collection.add("Charley");
        collection.add("Baker");
    }
}
```

Output: Able Baker aBle Charley Baker

And our job is to change that code so that it fits a different main that I'm not able to edit:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Proj09{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Proj09Runner runner = new Proj09Runner();

        Collection <String> collection = runner.getCollection();

        collection.add("Able");
        collection.add("Baker");
        collection.add("aBle");
        collection.add("Charley");
        collection.add("Baker");

        Iterator <String> iter = collection.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(iter.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

So far, I've been playing with the Proj09Runner class:

```
class Proj09Runner extends Proj09{
    public void getCollection(){
    System.out.println("My Name.");
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Small change to the output, I'm supposed to add my name.
Desired output:
My Name
Able Baker aBle Charley Baker

But I keep getting different errors that go back to the line `Collection <String> collection = runner.getCollection();` in the main I'm not supposed to change. I'll get called out on void's not being able to be converted to `Collection <String>` or "invalid method declaration; return type required."

Could y'all help me figure out why I'm getting those messages and what they mean so that I can avoid them in the future?

Thanks, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: You have to change the return type of `getCollection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to go ahead and share the answer:

```
import java.util.*;

class Proj09Runner{
    public Collection <String> getCollection(){
        System.out.println("Name.");
        Collection collection = new ArrayList();
        return collection;
    }
}
```

I couldn't go with TreeSet because it doesn't accept duplicates and so would only print "Baker" once, so I went with ArrayList instead.

Thanks a bunch for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

This for sure needs improvement :

```
Collection <String> collection = runner.getCollection();
```

this does not return a `Collection<String>`, note your method returns nothing.

```
public void getCollection(){
```

Either your method return type and definition changes something like :

```
public Collection<String> getCollection(){ //followed by corresponding definition
```

Or you can simply use

```
Collection <String> collection = new HashSet() ; //whatever your collection pertain to
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Collection<String> getCollection(){
        Collection collection = new TreeSet();
        Populator.fillIt(collection);
        Iterator iter = collection.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(iter.next());
        }
    System.out.println();
    return collection;
    }
```

your `getCollection method` is returning `nothing`. it should return a `collection`

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying this and it seems to be a good direction. Keeping the main:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Proj09{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Proj09Runner runner = new Proj09Runner();

        Collection <String> collection = runner.getCollection();

        collection.add("Able");
        collection.add("Baker");
        collection.add("aBle");
        collection.add("Charley");
        collection.add("Baker");

        Iterator <String> iter = collection.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            System.out.print(iter.next() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

I've now got:

```
class Proj09Runner{
    public Collection<String> getCollection(){
        return "Hailey";
  }
}
```

I didn't want to reiterate what was already in the main as it seemed unnecessary. Returning the string "Hailey" addressed the old error, but a new one has popped up.

```
error: cannot find symbol
public Collection<String> getCollection(){
       ^
symbol: class Collection
location: class Proj09Runner
```

Do you know what that type of error indicates?

Our last unit was about inheritance, and I played with "Proj09Runner extends Proj09{" but it didn't seem to have an effect.